# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему код не является верным? (Яндекс практикум. Введение Python, урок 6, тема словари )

Tags: python, list, словари

Задание: Напечатайте о каждом из друзей такое сообщение

> `<имя_друга>` живёт в городе `<название_города>`

Хочу понять имеет ли мой вариант на жизнь? (даже если он более громоздкий)
P.S. Скобки в `print` менял на круглые - не изменилось ничего
Буду очень благодарен!

```
friends =  {
  'Серёга': 'Омск',
  'Соня': 'Москва',
  'Дима': 'Челябинск',
  'Айгуль': 'Казань',   
  'Алёна': 'Белгород',
  'Даниил': 'Санкт-Петербург',
  'Лев': 'Тула',
  'Валера': 'Сыктывкар',
  'Антон': 'Ялта',
  'Карен': 'Краснодар'
  }

  a = len(friends.values())
  for i in range(0,a-1)
    print(friends.keys[i],"живёт в городе",friends.value[i])
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(friends.keys[i],"живёт в городе",friends.value[i])
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Очевидно, что не имеет т.к. не работает

Comment: Ошибка `object is not subscriptable` говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь применить обращение по индексу через квадратные скобки там, где это невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала о том, почему не работает.
Интерпретатор вам сообщает: `builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`
Это значит, что вы пытаетесь применить обращение по индексу `[i]` к методу. А методы (`keys` и `values`) надо вызывать. Попробуем починить:

```
print(friends.keys()[i], "живёт в городе", friends.values()[i])
```

Теперь ошибка другая:

```
'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

К результату вызова функции keys() тоже нельзя применить квадратные скобки. Почему? Если мы пороемся в документации по стандартной библиотеке Python, то обнаружим, что методы [`keys()` и `values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) возвращают некий [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), который в свою очередь является неупорядоченным множеством (`set`).

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable.

Поэтому и обратиться к его элементам по индексу нельзя.

Что же делать? Довольно идиоматичным способом для Python будет перебор элементов словаря сразу в виде пар (tuple). А вывод аккуратнее будет отформатировать через [f-строки](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).

```
for name, city in friends.items():
  print(f"{name} живет в городе {city}")
```